# C# Visual studio : adding columns to localdb reset all data

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017, localdb

I was working with `VisualStudio 2017 C#` and `localdb2016` I created  a table in server explorer's database desginer window with `10` columns added `X` rows.

I have already set `copy if newer` so rows wont get deleted everytime

but when i try to add a **new** **column** `(11th column)` all of my rows (even in other tables!) get deleted !

why ?

Here is my Table code generated from desginer .... :

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerTable] (
    [Id]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [company] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [email]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [phone1]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [phone2]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [address] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [fax]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [phone3]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [date]    DATETIME      DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

UPDATE 1 :

> `ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerTable ADD column_b VARCHAR(20) NULL, column_c INT NULL ;`

does that code remove old columns (b and c) if they **exists**?
 is it a good idea to do that everytime app starts? (for upgrading purpose)

Comment: Why would you add existing column every time the app start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Transact-SQL query

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerTable ADD column_b VARCHAR(20) NULL, column_c INT NULL ;
```

This query will add 2 columns in your table -> First, b (VARCHAR[20]) & Second, c (INT).
To read more, 
[ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The query will not remove any existing column because it is an alter query that means it alter the table as you mention. Adding existing column doesn't alter table. So, no changes.

Comment: do i have to put it in T-SQL window or execute it in my C# app as a querry?

Comment: also if column_b exist will it remove data or does nothing?

Comment: @Disco4uf you can execute it from c# using sqlclient

Comment: @Disco4uf Do some trial run to discover. And inform if it doesn't work

Comment: oh that worked it actually dident remove my tables ! but is it a good idea to run it every time app starts ?? (for upgrading purpose)

Comment: @Disco4uf Of course NOT, it will hamper your speed. Accept as solution if it works. Thanks.